# deploy old Struts / Spring WAR application in JBoss EAP 7 / JVM8

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, wildfly

I'm having problem to deploy in **JBoss EAP7** in standalone mode in **Centos 7** running in **Java SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)**. I update the classes from Struts because another ERR ( Failed to define class org.apache.strutsel.taglib.tiles.ELPutTag ).

When I deploy I got this exceptions:

```
2016-10-24 15:41:51 ERR [ServerService Thread Pool -- 111] (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'userLoginListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logService' while setting bean property 'logService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'logService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'logService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getFile(ClassPathResource.java:167)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:678)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:796)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:592)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
15:41:51,613 ERR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./###: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./###: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'userLoginListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logService' while setting bean property 'logService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'logService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'userLoginListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logService' while setting bean property 'logService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'logService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'userLoginListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logService' while setting bean property 'logService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'logService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:796)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:592)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'logService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:261)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:261)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ERR creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/###light-data-source.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:261)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [bus/valueobjects/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getFile(ClassPathResource.java:167)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:678)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
    ... 49 more
```

The classes and XMLs exist in following path "vfs:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects", Any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I discovery the root problem.

In XMl bean file, I change the property "**mappingDirectoryLocations**" from "*classpath:###/valueobjects/" to "file:#/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/deployments/###.war/WEB-INF/classes/bus/valueobjects/*".

Absolute path is not a good solution, but I got something to investigate, maybe An weird environment relate to JBoss classloader and Spring classloader... I guess.